# How to add languages in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add multiple languages in my elastic search so that i can use multiple language.
languages like.

"Burmese"
"Ukrainian"
"Khmer"
"Vietnamese"

I am using elastic-search 8.3.3 and kibana 8.3.3

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post detailed index mapping & document, perhaps this mapping could help

```
{
  "article_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "title" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "ukrainian" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "brazilian" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When searching, you could point to the desired language field